# Access element in function result

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

Why this Fortran code is incorrect?

```
function foo(x)
real x
real, dimension(3) :: foo
foo = (/1, 2, 3/)
end
```

... and in main program

```
print*, foo(x)(1)
```

Why we cannot access element in function result directly?

Comment: Because the standard does not know such syntax. The question does not have almost any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you ponder your own question

```
Why we cannot access element in function result directly?
```

I suggest you also write lines, in your main program, such as

```
res = foo(x)     ! having taken care to declare res appropriately
print*, res(1)
```

and get on with your coding.  It's just not syntactically-correct to index a function call the way you've tried.

So one answer to your original question is *because that's the way Fortran's syntax is defined* to which you might be prompted to respond *why is Fortran's syntax defined that way ?*  Even if this process turns up an answer in the form of reference to the roots of the design of Fortran (now over 50 years old) you're still going to have to modify your code to align with Fortran's syntax. For sure your compiler isn't going to say *you know, what you've written is better than the syntax I've been programmed to accept, I'll compile that up right now ...*

Comment: Very thanks, I thought that I forgot Fortran syntax. Or I'm crazy) IMHO, it's unclear syntax, but c'est la vie

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30152873) tells all needed.  As you're after syntactic niceness I'll address one thing in there: "having taken care to declare res appropriately".

One could use an associate construct to hide this a little.

```
associate (res => foo(x))
  print *, res(1)
end associate
```

This changes nothing in that answer other than reducing junk declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I forget about 'associate'. Local var 'res' looks better.