# fortran coordinate function f(x)

Tags: math, fortran, coordinates, fortran90

I need do some math calculations in FORTRAN 90. For this I need to use the coordinate functions of a other function. A example that following

```
program test1
implicit none
    integer :: i, Nend
    double precision :: step, a, b
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: t

    Nfim = 10
    a = 0.d0
    b = 1.d0
    step = (b-a)/Nend

    allocate(t(0:Nfim))
    t(0) = a
    do i=0,Nfim
        t(i+1) = t(i) + step
        write(*,*) i, t(i), f(t(i)),g(t(i))
    end do

contains
    function f(x)
        implicit none
        double precision :: f
        double precision, dimension(2) :: f
            f(1) = x-1.d0
            f(2) = 2.d0*x
        return
        end function

    function g(x)
        implicit none
        double precision :: x, g
            g = f(1)(x)+2.d0*f(2)(x)
        return
        end function
end program
```

im my prompt i have a return

```
34 |     g = f(1)(x)+2.d0*f(2)(x)
   |           1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

i did understand so that in f(...)  the ''...'' = x and not  ''...'' = 1. I don't wold do like using f1, because in my program the dimension of function f wold be changeable that the program will by applicable in other situations, and this will save me of some time. Can you help me? Thanks you for now!

Comment: edit1:   "double precision :: f"  --->  "double precision :: x" . Sorry.

Comment: edit2: "Nfim = 10
"->"Nend = 10" ,  "allocate(t(0:Nfim))"->"allocate(t(0:Nend))" , "do i=0,Nfim"->"do i=0,Nend"   Sorry.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. If you want to make an edit, use the [edit] button above, do not use comments. However, first of all read the duplicate link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152605/access-element-in-function-result please. What you are trying to do is simply not possible. You cannot access any elements or components of a function result. You first have to assign the function result to something else.